# Probability of drawing three different colours.

Tags: probability

I have a bag filled with 10 balls each of different colour.Now i have picked one ball randomly and after looking at the colour i will drop the ball again in the bag.I have repeated this for 10 times.For all the 10 drawing i will note the colour of the balls drawn.What is probability that i will draw balls of only three different colours and that too  1,4,9th drawing should not be of same colour.

Comment: "*and that too all the 3 different coloured should be the 1,4,9th drawing*"  I don't follow this line... are you saying that among the first three draws all are the same color, the fourth draw is a different color, then the fifth through eighth draws are all one of the first two colors seen, the ninth draw is a new not yet seen color, and the tenth draw is any of the already seen colors?  For example using numbers something like `1112122131`?  If so, just approach directly with multiplication principle of probability.

Comment: It mean that the 1st,4th,9th drawings should be of different colours.

Comment: @mechanics you did not clarify at all. Please give examples of valid drawings.

Comment: @mechanics So are you saying that among the first three balls drawn, they can be of different colors?  For example `1232123231` is a valid drawing?  Noting that the first ball's color is `1`, the fourth ball's color is `2`, and the ninth ball's color is `3`?  If that were the case, the suggestion of approaching with multiplication principle is still the way to go, noting that rather than drawing the balls "in order" you can first draw the first ball, then draw the fourth ball before any others, then draw the ninth ball, then finally go back and draw all the remaining balls for the other places

Comment: Let us i draw black,green,yellow.The first draw can be Y or B or G.Let us say i draw Y.Then 4th should be either B or G.Let us say i drew B.Then the 9th should be G.All the remaining can be of any colour among these

Answer (score 1):

By your procedure any combination of 10 picks is just as likely as any other.

- How many ways are there of making the 10 picks? Obviously $10^{10}$.
- How many different sets of 3 colors can be chosen from the $10$? That
  is $10 \choose 3$ (note that to have the 1st, 4th, and 9th balls of
  different colors requires the 3 colors to be distinct).
- How many ways are there of making the 1st, 4th, and 9th picks to be
  of different colors? $3! = 6$.
- How many ways of making the remaining 7 picks from those same 3 colors? $3^7$

So there are ${10 \choose 3}(3!)(3^7)$ possible picks matching your conditions, which gives a probability of $$\frac{{10 \choose 3}(3!)(3^7)}{10^{10}}= \frac{10!\times3^7}{7!\times10^{10}} = \frac {3^9}{2^6 \times 5^9} \approx 0.000157464$$

Comment: I should note that InterstellarProbe gave the same result (from a slightly different calculation), but later deleted it, declaring it is wrong. However, I do not see any problem. The comment mechanics made to it makes no sense to me. Both InterstellarProbe and my versions do guarantee that the 1st, 4th, and 9th picks are different colors. And the probility of just picking 3 colors without requiring the those picks to be distinct is $$\frac{{10 \choose 3}3^{10}}{10^{10}}$$ which is not the same.